# Create conditional query in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6

I want to turn this query into laravel way

`select * from brands inner join products on brands.id = products.brandid where categoryid = '1' and (productname like 'search' or brands.name = 'search')`

I have tried this

```
$search = $request->allsearch;

$product = DB::table('brands')->join('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brandid')
            ->where('categoryid', '=', 1)
            ->where(function ($product, $search) {
            $product->where('productname','like','%'.$search.'%')
                     ->orWhere('brands.name','like','%'.$search.'%');
           });
```

but I got an error
`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

I've already tried using `when` but it didn't work out.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In where callback function you should pass query instance and for additional params you can pass it in use()

```
    $product = DB::table('brands')->join('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brandid')
                ->where('categoryid', '=', 1)
                ->where(function ($query)use($search) {
                 if(!empty($search)){
                $query->where('productname','like','%'.$search.'%')
                         ->orWhere('brands.name','like','%'.$search.'%');
}
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the other answers query as it is horrible, there is a method specially for this... [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)... it is one of the best you can read...

```php
$search = $request->allsearch;

$product = DB::table('brands')
    ->join('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brandid')
    ->where('categoryid', 1)
    ->when(!empty($search), function ($query) use ($search) {
        return $query->where(function ($product) use ($search) {
            return $product->where('productname', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('brands.name', 'like', "%$search%");
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the laravel way... And try to avoid 100% the use of `DB::table(...)->join()`... Taylor and the Laravel team took the time to create [`Relations`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction) for this... Don't uglify your code...

Comment: .query as it is horrible means what it mean .are you saying query performance horrible or code quality horrible

Comment: I mean Code Quality. Remember you are not using relations !!!

Comment: i agreed. i have given only solution fix op issue .yes but if we give relations then it iwll take time. i only answered  based  on issue.

Comment: I know, I am still using the horrible code OP gave. I mostly mean that you are using an IF badly indented to serve as my `when` addition.

Comment: .i agreed your point.initially i though you are referring query is returning invalid result or query performance issue. :)